# Gulp-minify-css does not produce output files

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I have set up a very simple `gulpfile.js` There are only two task - 'sass' and 'minify-js'. These two tasks are fired by the task 'watch' when a change is detected. It all seems to be working well: Gulp is listening for changes, *.scss files are compiled into CSS, the console generates output as expected, without any errors. However, the CSS files do not get minified there are no output files from the 'minify-css' task whatsoever.

Why is 'minify-css' not working? What am I missing here?

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('plugins/SoSensational/styles/sass/*.scss')
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('plugins/SoSensational/styles/dest/'));
});

gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
    gulp.src('plugins/SoSensational/styles/dest/*.css')
            .pipe(minifyCSS())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('plugins/SoSensational/styles/dest/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('plugins/SoSensational/styles/sass/*.scss', ['sass', 'minify-css']);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a race condition. Sass and MinifyCSS are executed in parallel, might be that your Sass task isn't done when you're already running MinifyCSS. Sass should be a dependency, so you have two options:

1. Make Sass a dependency from minifycss:

   ```
   gulp.task('minify-css', ['sass'], function() {
       return gulp.src('plugins/SoSensational/styles/dest/*.css')
           .pipe(minifyCSS())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('plugins/SoSensational/styles/dest/'));
   });

   gulp.task('watch', function() {
        gulp.watch('plugins/SoSensational/styles/sass/*.scss', ['minify-css']);
   });
   ```
2. Have one task that does both!

   ```
   gulp.task('sass', function() {
        return gulp.src('plugins/SoSensational/styles/sass/*.scss')
            .pipe(sass())
            .pipe(minifyCSS())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('plugins/SoSensational/styles/dest/'));
   });
   ```

The latter one is actually the preferred version. You save yourself a lot of time if you don't have an intermediate result

Btw: Don't forget the return statements

Comment: This is the right answer. I just needed to make ['sass'] a dependency. I went with the first option since I needed the intermediate results. By the way, I'm just wondering some tasks require `return` inside the anonynous function while others don't. This is even evident in usage examples of different gulp plugins. Why this inconsistency ?

Comment: The return statement tells Gulp that you use a stream, and such Gulp is able to arrange the parallel execution of tasks a lot better. The alternative would be using the done callback. Your watch task doesn't need one, because the `gulp.watch` call will be the only statement executed, no need to orchestrate this.

Comment: @ddprrt I tried the second version, but the system tells me there is no gulp watch. Where should I put the gulp watch?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of an old question but thought I'd throw this out there because it's something that's helped me. To build on the answer from ddprrt, I'd recommend changing:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
     return gulp.src('plugins/SoSensational/styles/sass/*.scss')
         .pipe(sass())
         .pipe(minifyCSS())
         .pipe(gulp.dest('plugins/SoSensational/styles/dest/'));
});
```

to:

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
     return gulp.src('plugins/SoSensational/styles/sass/*.scss')
         .pipe(sass('site.css'))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('plugins/SoSensational/styles/dest/'))
         .pipe(minifyCSS())
         .pipe(rename('site.min.css'))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('plugins/SoSensational/styles/dest/'));
});
```

This allows you to debug with the un-minified CSS and deploy the minified version.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the gulp-minify-css is deprecated. Use gulp-clean-css instead.

Click here(https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css "npm-clean-css")!